# Search and work with datas from a url-import webpage

Tags: php

i try to get the sourcecode of a external website to load them and work with this code. I need to work with the content of some div's - named by a class or a specific name.

At first i get the sourcecode in this way

```
$url='http://www.example.com/site.html';
$page = file_get_contents($url);
```

Now i have to search the $page for some divs, for example
search for a div with name="test1" or class="test2", also i have to look for some other elements like  with specific names or classes.

Now i can use str_replace, explore etc. to built a long an inefectiv way to do that - mayme someone can tell me how i can do this in a simple and faster way? Maybe i can load the sourcecode in a kind of array or something else?

thanks a lot

For me only file_get_contents works - file_get_html wont work!?

Comment: `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` are your friends for this type of task

Comment: This package might help too; I used to use this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very quick, basic example of how you might use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` to find elements within a page. You will want to read the manual I suspect for [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) and probably find a good `XPath` cheatsheet ~ such as [this](https://devhints.io/xpath)

```
$url='http://www.example.com/site.html';
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

$query='//div[ contains( @class,"test" ) ]';
$col=$xp->query( $query );

if( $col && $col->length>0 ){
    foreach($col as $node)echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: hi, the first 3 steps works for me. How can i go on without xpath? By the way i dont know how i can implent xpath - i find no infos on the site about installation and so...

Comment: in the $dom i have only javascript code not the end sourcecode of the $url - what i do wrong?

Comment: Please explain what you mean - or give example

Comment: i think it is impossible, php could not catch the content wich is generate by the browser!?

Comment: Please provide the actual url